# Ошибка с прокси python+requests: The handshake operation timed out

Tags: python, requests, ssl, https, proxy

не могу понять в чем проблема. Скрипт, использующий для запросов requests+прокси на нескольких серверах отрабатывает с ошибкой. На настроенных серверах или пк скрипт работает без ошибок (т.е дело не в коде!), при копировании на чистые сервера появляется такая ошибка. Обновлял и устанавливал на сервера все, что можно. Проблема остается на 3.5 и 3.7 питонах. Гугл пустой на эту тему, что мне предоставить, чтобы можно было понять, в чем проблема? Полный текст ошибки:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.vk.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /method/groups.getMembers
(Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('_ssl.c:629: The handshake operation timed out',)))
```

**UPD**

Строка запроса:

```py
res = requests.get(self.base_url.format(method, "&".join(['%s=%s                                                                                                                                                          
 ' % (i, kwargs[i]) for i in kwargs])), proxies={
"http": "http://"+self.proxy,
"https": "https://"+self.proxy}, timeout=15)
```

self.proxy выглядит так: `login:pass@87.247.145.175:8000`

Comment: покажите, как в коде подключаются прокси?

Comment: обновил вопрос, добавил строку запроса

Comment: еще раз обращу внимание: скопированный на другой сервер этот же код работает

Comment: может, на "чистых серверах" настроена блокировка прокси?

Comment: Да вроде хостер один и тот же, сам я ничего такого не делал. Как проверить, есть ли блокировка? Писал в поддержку хостера, они сказали, что проблема не на их стороне

Comment: Попробуйте увеличить timeout или вообще уберите его, т.к., возможно, сервер, с которого отправляется запрос, не успевает соединиться с прокси по SSL. Либо исходный сервер не поддерживает соединение по SSL, что вряд ли, но все-таки. И то, что хостер один и тот же вовсе не значит, что все ваши хосты на одном физическом сервере.

Comment: Если увеличить таймаут, ошибка сохраняется. Если убрать - появляется SSLError Unknown protocol (с http/https префиксом перед прокси, полагаю, ошибка не связана). Конечный сервер - vk.com
если проблема хостера - что мне им написать тогда? Раз они уже отписались
если предположить, что проблема в неустановленных/необновленных пакетах - как мне узнать, в каких?

Comment: А прокси точно поддерживает подключение по SSL? Скорей всего, вам надо использовать схему только с **https**, http не нужен, т.к. VK соединяет по SSL. Попробуйте с сервера хостера соединиться через этот прокси к обычной версии сайта - vk.com, а еще лучше на разные другие, например, [2ip](https://2ip.ru/) и посмотрите, что возвращает `r.text`

Comment: `requests` использует пакеты `certifi, chardet, idna`. certifi - работает с корневыми сертификатами, проверяет подлинность и т.д. и т.п. Попробуйте обновить сам `requests` и все его зависимости

Comment: Обновил requests, попробовал убрать http или делать запросы на другие сайты - проблема остается. Кстати, если убрать timeout, то ошибка меняется на `Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol`
Тестил это все уже в интерактивном режиме, т.е код был минимально необходимый для запроса

Comment: `curl` с этими прокси работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась даунгрейдом `requests` до версии `2.23.0`